# How to download a video using telethon

Tags: python-3.x, telegram, telethon

I'm working on [telethon](https://github.com/LonamiWebs/Telethon/blob/master/telethon/telegram_client.py#L811) `download_media` and `_download_document` methods for downloading video from telegram. My code is something like this:

```
def callback(update): 
        Channel_Entity = client.get_entity(Channel_List) #Get specific Channel information

        file_name = str(document_id)+'.mp4'
        current_path = os.getcwd()
        file_path_gif = current_path+'/media/gif'
        file = open(os.path.join(file_path_gif,file_name),'wb')

        if isinstance(update, UpdateNewChannelMessage): #Check Update message in channel
            if update.message.to_id.channel_id == Channel_Entity.id:

                client._download_document(update.message.media, file, update.message.date, progress_callback=None)

                # OR 

                client.download_media(update.message, file, progress_callback=None)
```

But when a video is sent to channel and downloaded with this code, the video is not playable and the player prints this message: 
Cannot render the file.
This code works on images and gif files but does not work on video files. What should i do?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I hope this code will help you. I used `Telethon V0.19`, but the previous versions are pretty much the same.

```
from telethon import TelegramClient

api_id = XXXXXXX
api_hash = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
phone_number = '+98XXXXXXXXX'
################################################
channel_username = 'tehrandb'
################################################

client = TelegramClient('session_name',
                    api_id,
                    api_hash)

assert client.connect()
if not client.is_user_authorized():
    client.send_code_request(phone_number)
    me = client.sign_in(phone_number, input('Enter code: '))

# ---------------------------------------
msgs = client.get_messages(channel_username, limit=100)
for msg in msgs.data:
    if msg.media is not None:
        client.download_media(message=msg)
```

Answer (score 0):

2024 updated code!

Save this file into a python file and run it....

```
from telethon import TelegramClient, events
import telethon.tl.types

api_id = id
api_hash = hash

channel = group/channel username

client = TelegramClient('anon', api_id, api_hash)

async def process_messages():
   # You can use any chat object here
   chat = await client.get_entity(channel)

   async for message in client.iter_messages(chat):
    if (
          hasattr(message, 'media') and
          hasattr(message.media, 'document') and
          hasattr(message.media.document, 'mime_type') and
          message.media.document.mime_type == 'video/mp4'
      ):

        await  client.download_media(message=message , file='file_name.mp4')
        # The message is a video message
        print(f'Found video message: {message.id}')

with client:
    client.loop.run_until_complete(process_messages())
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).